# I have to display task name and owner-name id into jsp page which i am returning from spring mvc controller. But its not displaying

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am returning list of object and I have to display task name and owner name id but I am stuck what to do in `controller.js` and `userNotification.jsp` file to display those two fields. I am using `MongoDB` database. I chekced that data is being returned to controller. Please help.

**controller.js**

```
releaseApp.controller('UserNotificationController', function($scope, $http) {
    //console.log="Inside Controller";
    $scope.msg1 = "test2";
     $http.get('fetchTaskForApproval').success(function (response) {  
        $scope.taskDetails = response;
        //console.log('success');
     }).error(function(status) {
        // console.log(('No task created') + ': ' + status);
     });
});
```

**userNotification.jsp**

```
<div>
    <h3>Task Pending For Approval</h3>
    <b>{{msg1}}</b>
    <b>{{stat}}</b>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Task</th>
            <th class="text-center">Owner</th>
            <th class="text-center">Authorize</th>
        </tr>
        <div ng-repeat="task in taskDetails">
        <tr>
            <td>{{task.name}}</td>
            <td>{{task.owners.ownerName.id}}</td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="submit" name="approveTask" value="Approve" />
                    <input type="submit" name="rejectTask" value="Reject"/>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </div>              
    </table>
</div>
```

**userNotification.java**

```
@Controller
public class UserNotificationController {

    @Autowired
    MongoService mongoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fetchTaskForApproval", method = RequestMethod.GET)       
    public List<TaskDAO> notification(){
        System.out.println("entering notification");
        List<TaskDAO> taskDAOLists=new ArrayList<TaskDAO>();
        taskDAOLists = mongoService.fetchPendingTask("Assigned");
        System.out.println("exiting notification");
        System.out.println(taskDAOLists);
        return taskDAOLists;
    }
}
```

Comment: use should look at what exactly `response` contain in ajax success,,I believe you need to do `$scope.taskDetails = response.taskDetails ;`

Comment: No it didn't work. I got message "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once" in chrome console.

Comment: That means you are referring angular.js file twice on page, you should remove one of the reference

Comment: I resolved that issue but still i'm getting error message :http://localhost:8084/RelMan/fetchTaskForApproval 404  not found


    <html><head><u>The requested resource () is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.8</h3></body></html>

Comment: the action which you are trying to access is not available on server side

Comment: Is it like i can use ModelandView in controller only if we are passing value from jsp page through form?